# Show that $(R^n,\| \|_p)$ is a Banach space

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $p \in R_{\ge 1}$. Let $\| \|_p:R^n \to R$ be givven by $$\|(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)\|=(|a_1|^p+...+|a_n|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

Show that $(R^n,\| \|_p)$ is a Banach space.

I want to show that if $(x_1,x_2,...)$ is Cauchy in $R^n$, then this sequence converges in $R^n$. My steps are as follows:

(1)Show that $(\|x_1\|_p,\|x_2\|_p,...)$ is Cauchy.

(2)Since $R$ with the usual norm is complete, $(\|x_1\|_p,\|x_2\|_p,...)$ converges to $\|x\|_p$.

(3)Show that $(x_1,x_2,...)$ converges to $x$.

I did first two steps and I don't know how to do the last part or does anyone have better ideas of how to do this proof?

Comment: I don't think steps 1 and 2 are going to help with step 3. You can't conclude convergence of $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ to $x$ from the fact that $\|x_1\|, \|x_2\|,\ldots$ converges to $\|x\|$; in general, it's not true. (Consider a bunch of random points on the unit sphere, for example.)

Answer (score 2):

Taking $\|\cdot\|_{p}$ simply does not help. Actually you need to show that the coordinate sequence is Cauchy and hence convergent, that is, if $x_{1}=(a_{1,1},a_{1,2},...,a_{1,n})$, $x_{2}=(a_{2,1},a_{2,2},...,a_{2,n})$ is such a sequence, then $\{a_{1,1},a_{2,1},...\}$, $\{a_{1,2},a_{2,2},...\}$ are all Cauchy, then the limits of each of these constitute the limit of $\{x_{n}\}$ in coordinatewise.